# An algorithm for semi-random sorting (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections

I'm making a turn-based RPG game, and my method that sorts all "Actor" objects in the order in which they all attack sorts them completely randomly. I, however, want to improve this method so that an "agility" stat that every actor has is able to improve their roll. I've looked at several methods in the Collections class, and Arrays as well, but didn't seem to find anything that does what I want.

Right now, I'm thinking about getting a random int between 1 and 100, and having the agility score improve the odds. I tried separate ArrayLists for the Integers and a HashMap... but a no go on those.

My method as it is now:

```
// getFriendlies(), getHostiles(), and attack_order are all ArrayLists

public void calculateAttackOrder() {
        attack_order.addAll(getFriendlies());
        attack_order.addAll(getHostiles());
        Collections.shuffle(attack_order);
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Actor implements Comparable {

    private int agility;
    private int randomAgility;

    private int getInitiative() {
        //You can change this method as you see fit
        return randomAgility + this.agility;
    }

    public void generateRandomAgility() {
        this.randomAgility = (Math.random() * 100);
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Actor other = (Actor)other;
        return this.getInitiative() - other.getInitiative();
    }
}
```

Then you can call

```
for (Actor a : attack_order) {
    a.generateRandomAgility();
}
Collections.sort(attack_order);
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work.  Because the comparator may give different results when applied to the same units repeatedly, the internal logic of the `Collections.sort` function might break.

Comment: I modified the solution to account for that.

Comment: Thank you! Simple yet effective.

Comment: This won't work (properly) and will give unpredictable results because the value being compared changes every comparison, breaking the contract of Comparable (see javadoc for more info)

Comment: @Bohemian That has been accounted for. If you look, it goes through each Actor before hand and calls generateRandomAgility() first, then when the compareTo() is called it uses the pre-generated random number to compare with, so the value does not change between each comparison.

Comment: This is a bad design, because you've added something to the class that has nothing to do with the class - the randomisation part. That should be *external* to the class and further the class should know nothing about it. See my solution for an example of the right way to do it. Essentially, for a solution to be a good design, it should work with the Player being an interface, not a class. That way you're ensuring the class doesn't need any special state to be soted inside it.

Comment: Did you mean the Actor should be an interface? Making Actor a class as opposed to an interface doesn't change much in terms of object design, and if there is behavior that is specific to all Actors it doesn't make sense for it to go anywhere else In this case I think it is simpler, cleaner, and easier to understand.

I would agree with your solution if there was a need to plug in different comparators, but unless that is absolutely necessary I would consider your solution to be over-architected and adding unneeded complexity to the code.

Answer (score 6):

Use Collections.sort() and provide a Comparator that uses a combination of a random number and agility to compute the rank.

Here's an implementation that would work. Note here that `Player` is the simplest possible interface that will work:

```
public interface HasAgility {
    /** @return value between 0 and 1 */
    double getAgility();
}

public class Player implements HasAgility {
    double agility;
    double getAgility( return agility; );
   // rest of class
}

public class MoveComparator implements Comparator<HasAgility> {
    /** Need to calculate the agility once, and keep using that same value, for each player */
    private Map<HasAgility, Double> playerAgilities = new HashMap<HasAgility, Double>();

    private Double getRandomAgility(HasAgility player) {
        Double randomAgility = playerAgilities.get(player);
        if (randomAgility == null) {
            randomAgility = Math.random() * player.getAgility();
            playerAgilities.put(player, randomAgility);
        }
        return randomAgility;
    }

    public int compare(HasAgility o1, HasAgility o2) {
        return getRandomAgility(o1).compareTo(getRandomAgility(o2));
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Player> players= new ArrayList<Player>();
    Collections.sort(players, new MoveComparator());
}
```

The important thing to note is that once calculated, a player's random agile score must be reused again for all later comparisons. This Comparator class s designed to be used once only (the map is required to be empty at the start of its use).

Comment: As long as it doesn't compute the random number each time it fires compare!

Comment: @glowcoders comment is right on, and this is tougher than it seems.

Comment: For what it's worth, in Python instead of providing a comparator to the sort routine, you provide a function that maps the element type to some type that is comparable. For this purpose it has the neat feature that it's called exactly once per element and the result stored under the covers throughout the sort, so it can involve a random value without breaking the algorithm. You could wrap the normal Java sort routine in an adaptor to mimic this.

Answer (score 6):

Your question doesn't go into much detail about the requirements about how agility influences your attack order, but I assume that you meant one of these two:

1. If one unit has higher agility than another, it **always** attacks first.
2. If one unit has higher agility than another, it **usually** attacks first.

If the first of these is true (units with higher agility always attack first), then what you're looking for is a way of permuting the array subject to the restriction that units with higher agility always end up before units of lower agility, but with everything else done randomly.  One way to do this is as follows:

1. If you have N units, assign the numbers 1 ... N to the units at random.  Don't assign the same number twice.
2. Sort the units into ascending order as follows:

   - Any unit with higher agility than another unit comes first.
   - Of two untis that are tied, whichever has the higher random number comes first.

You can show that this approach will arrange the units so that all units of a certain agility are randomly permuted relative to one another, but always come before lower-agility units.  This takes time O(n log n) and can be done using `Collections.sort`, `Collections.shuffle`, and an appropriate `Comparator`.

If, on the other hand, you want the ordering to be random but **influenced** by the agility, you may want to think about using some sort of random distribution that can be controlled by some parameter.  For example, you might assign each unit a priority drawn from a normal distribution whose mean is the agility and whose standard deviation is some reasonably large number (say, 20).  This would mean that units with more agility are more likely to move before units with less agility, though there is a large amount of randomness.  The advantage of this approach is that by tweaking the underlying distribution and its parameters (mean and variance in the case of a normal distribution), you can fine-tune to what extent the agility measure factors in.

As an example of a very simple approach, you might model unit speed as

> priority = e<sup>(agility / 100) + random(1, 2)</sup>

Here, the more agility you have, the greater that your priority is.  Increasing the amount of randomness changes the extent to which agility matters.  Of course, this might be a bit skewed because each marginal increase in agility has more meaning, so you may want to replace the exponential with something like a [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

Hope this helps!

Comment: His question seems to indicate he wants to use the *usually* attacks first options. I really like the idea of using a distribution function in this case.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are various pencil-and-paper RPGs that randomise turn order based on agility or some other per-character value that might as well be called agility here. No doubt there are all kinds of weirdness out there, but the most common are (mathematically equivalent to) either: A) take the agility and add a dice roll. So the distribution of the roll is either uniform (one die) or else some approximation to normal by adding multiple dice. B) something involving a number of dice equal to agility, so that both the mean *and* the variance depend on the agility.

Comment: Not to say your ideas aren't better, using more computational power than the average nerd's mental arithmetic, just that there's prior work in this field out there :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't touch the Actor internals, you need a way of associating a 'roll' for each actor for a complete sort (which probably includes many calls to compare), but which is forgotten by the next sort.

In that case, I would do this:

```
public class ActorComparable {
  Actor actor;
  int roll;

  public ActorComparable(Actor actor) {
    this.actor = actor;
    roll = Math.Random(100) + actor.getAgility();
  }

  public getActor() {
    return actor;
  }

  public getRoll() {
    return roll;
  }

  public int compareTo(Actor that) {
    return this.getRoll() - that.getRoll();
  }
}
```

Now when you want to sort an ArrayList of Actors, build an ArrayList of ActorComparables, sort those, and build a resulting list out of the ActorComparables.

Comment: Shouldn't your class implement Comparable<Actor> ?

Comment: This would mean he has to create a new ActorComparable for each actor every time he wants to re-sort the list... which means a ton of objects are going to be created and garbage collected each time.

Comment: It should implement `Comparable<ActorComparable>`.

Answer (score 1):

A whole example using a [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (a [SortedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) implementations that guarantees the elements are always ordered, using a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in this case):

```
class Actor {
    private int agility;
    private double weight = Math.random(); 

    public Actor(int agility) {
        this.agility = agility;
    }
    public double getComputedAgility() {
        return agility * weight;
    }
}

public class TestRandomActors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Actor> collection = new TreeSet<Actor>(
                new Comparator<Actor>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Actor a1, Actor a2) {
                        return 
                            a1.getComputedAgility() > a2.getComputedAgility() ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                }
            );

        collection.add(new Actor(30));
        collection.add(new Actor(31));
        collection.add(new Actor(60));

        for (Actor actor : collection)
            System.out.println("Actor with agility = " + actor.getComputedAgility());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think @Anthony answer is better than mine, because his solution only computes Math.random() once per Actor.  Could anyone confirm it?

Comment: No I think my solution might have the same problem... if it calls getInitiative() twice on one Actor while sorting it can return different values.

Comment: You are right, I've fixed it in my code.  This way the "random weight" is computed only once and never changes.  Now I deserve the accepted answer :)

Comment: I don't like this solution. It works well if you want to sort something once, but with a game you probably want to be able to re-order the Actors more than once and that requires a re-creating the TreeSet a lot, which will lead to unnecessary garbage collection...

Comment: Yes, you are right again. I've seen your modified answer that generates a new random weight for each new iteration. Now you deserve it.